# parsing in shell depending of the position in line

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

I have a small issue with a script shell.

Let's suppose that :

```
pos=80:1
```

I would like to use this variable in this syntax :

```
while read line

  word=${line:pos}

done < file.txt
```

But that doesn't work !

Just to precise, `word=$(line:80:1}` works fine.

Comment: Is this `bash`? `zsh`? `ksh`?

Comment: it's programed in bash.

Comment: Note that if `bash` parsed things differently, you were close: `${line:$pos}` could work if `bash` expanded `$pos` before trying to parse the `:` operator. But, alas, it does not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it out and pass the items independently.

```
pos=80:1
IFS=: read -r pos_start pos_len <<<"$pos"
word=${line:$pos_start:$pos_len}
```

Parameter expansions are syntax, and expansion results are parsed only as data, not as syntax, unless you use `eval`. This is desirable, intended behavior -- if it were otherwise, it would be impossible to write secure code in bash.

Comment: I would use `IFS=: read pos_start pos_len <<< $pos` to split the value.

Comment: @chepner, good call; that's a win on both terseness and readability. Edited appropriately.